# Match list of words by their order

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a Regular Expression to match a list of words (all of them) but by their order.
Lets say I have the words: `what` and `people`.

The string: `what people do` should match.

The string: `people don't like what they do` shouldn't match (because the words doesn't appear in the right order).

The string: `people are nice` shouldn't match because not all the words exists.

I have this Regex: `\b(?=.*WHAT)(?=.*PEOPLE)\b` and it works fine apart from the order part - when `people` appears before `what` it also return success.

Comment: Should it match "People want what people want"?  And I assume it should also match "What is it that people want".

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this regex without any look ahead.

```
^.*\bwhat\b.*\bpeople\b.*$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/38)

Comment: Might need word boundaries in case the OP doesn't want "what" to match "whatever".

Comment: How can i add word bounderies to this regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*?\bwhat\b.*?\bpeople\b).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/37